# onsubmit event not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, onsubmit

I have a form that uses the onsubmit event.

Tested in MS Blade, Chrome Version 67, Firefox Version 60 and the event works as expected.

This means a dialogue box appears and asks **"do you wish to proceed with the order and lists the item and value"**.  With options to select **"ok"** or **"cancel"**.

Tested in IE11 and the event fires but goes directly to the cancel option and reloads the page.

```
<form onsubmit="confirmBox()" action="#" name="order_form" id="order_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><div id="divPriceObj"></div></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Quantity</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" value="1"></td>
            <td>REQUIRED FIELD</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="description" id="description" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Total Price</label></td>
            <td><div id="totalPrice"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="resetQuantity()">Clear</button></td>                    
            <td><button type="button" onclick="calculateTotal()">Calculate Total</button></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>            
    </table>
</form>
```

The Javascript involved is

```
function confirmBox() {
var itemDesc = setDesc(getUrlVars()["description"]);
var itemPrice = document.forms["order_form"]["price"].value;
var itemQuantity = document.forms["order_form"]["quantity"].value;
var itemTotal = itemPrice * itemQuantity;

//check if form data is valid still

if (validateForm(price, quantity)) {
    var x = document.forms["order_form"]["price"].value;
    var y = document.forms["order_form"]["quantity"].value;
    var z = getUrlVars()["desc"];
    if (confirm('Do you wish to Proceed with the order of '
        + itemQuantity
        + ' ' + itemDesc
        + ' valued at $'
        + itemTotal + '?')) {
        close();
    } else {
        resetQuantity();
    }
} else {
//do nothing
//close();
}
}
```

I have not been able to fix this bug, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: surprised this works in other browsers to be honest - seeing as you're doing nothing to stop the default submit action

Comment: I was using hash as it does not need to go anywhere else other than some JS validation.  What would you do there instead, or should i literally point  it back to the same page?

Comment: @Jaromanda .. I tried adding a listener to stop the default submit action and it did not work.  thanx for your suggestion .. this is where i got the idea. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp also I need to use SELF as the url holds key data that is extracted to fill the form.